# C# XAML Using Converter to set the Height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, height, converters

I have created a converter called AspectRatioConverter which I want to use to set the Height of my MediaElement, but the converter is called only once at the start of the program and no longer during the program.

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MediaElement, Path=ActualWidth, 
                 Converter={StaticResource AspectRatioConverter}}"
```

The height of the MediaElement must change because I load different videos in it of different heights (the converter find the best height for the MediaElement taking in consideration the natural height and width of the video and the width of the MediaElement that is calculated using the width of the page.
So, how can I do this ? How can I modify the Height of the control during the program (using converters) ?

**Problem solved** :

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=MediaElement, Path=CurrentState, Converter={StaticResource AspectRatioConverter}}"
```

Comment: The converter should be called each time the binding is refreshed. That *should* be happening whenever `ActualWidth` changes value. Have you verified that's the case?

Comment: Well, the Width is not changing only when the Width of the screen is changing. But the Height of the MediaElement should be changing anytime I load a new video.

Comment: Maybe you could post some more XAML? If only the height is changing, though, then you will need to adjust your binding so that it is updating in response to something that is actually changing value.

Comment: Why can't you use [`MediaElement.Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) to maintain aspect ratio? `ActualWidth` doesn't have to change when you load new video. If your control stretches across whole width only area to display video will change and control size will stay the same

Comment: @dkozl,I know that I can do that, but I design my app for the Windows Store so I have to change the Width and the Height anyway so I thought that there is no point in loosing space (especially when the app is running on something like 1/2 or 1/4 of the screen).

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. @dlev, thanks a lot for explaining me how the binding is being refreshed. The ActualWidth was not changing so I had to find another property that changes.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem!

Comment: @TheQuestioner what property did you use ?

Comment: @eranotzap, I used CurrentState.